Rails error Couldn't find User without an ID
I'm stuck in creating a form for editing users in my admin panel. The administrator should be able to edit user roles and delete them, so I created a form but unfortunately I get an error
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID):

routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    root to: 'users#index'
    resources :users
  end
  get 'home', to: 'home#index'
  
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }

  devise_scope :user do
    root to: 'users/sessions#new'
    get 'sign_in', to: 'users/sessions#new'
    get '/users/sign_out', to: 'users/sessions#destroy'
    get 'search_users', to: 'users/sessions#search_users'
  end
end

app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
  def index
    #@users = User.all
    @users = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end

app/views/admin/users/index.html.erb
<div class="container-fluid admin-container">
  <div class="admin-h2-container">
    <h2 class="admin-h2">Zarządzanie użytkownikami</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="admin-table">
    <table class="table table-striped" style="width: 80%;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="admin-table">No</th>
          <th class="admin-table">Username</th>
          <th  class="admin-table">Imię</th>
          <th class="admin-table">Nazwisko</th>
          <th class="admin-table">Uprawnienia</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <body>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= simple_form_for [:admin, @users] do |f| %>
                <div class="form-inputs">
                  <%= f.input :id, input_html: {readonly: true } %>
                  <%= f.input :username, input_html: {readonly: true } %>
                  <%= f.input :first_name, input_html: {readonly: true } %>
                  <%= f.input :last_name, input_html: {readonly: true } %>
                  <%= f.input :role, input_html: {readonly: true } %>
                </div>
              <% end %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </body>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in the routs but I have no ideas on how to fix it. Can I count on help?

Your problem is not in routes, it is in controller

but routes are terrible too, you need to remove 4 lines after resources :users

@AntonBogdanov yes I already removed these 4 lines but still don't know what is wrong with controller. Can't edit in index method?

@users = User.all

OK, but I won't be able to update any records, it will be just showing data

for updating you need to add another action in controller, index action usually is only for rendering list of records

My goal was to create a form where user can update only one user value or delete it. So you suggest to use for this edit view not index?

your route resources :users creates routes  get /users/:id/edit, patch /users/:id where you can render form for 1 user and call updating request for 1 user

What would it look like if I wanted to enable only role update for every user?

just left field for role in form

I think I don't understand the defference between theese two routes edit_admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format) and admin_user PATCH /admin/users/:id(.:format)

@users = User.find(params[:id]), @users.each. Even you will have this id param (so strange for index action), you will get NoMethodError

I think I don't understand the defference between theese two routes start from some basic articles about HTTP verbs, something like https://dev.to/gabrielbabler/restful-understanding-the-most-common-http-verbs-and-return-codes-2g2o

edit displays the form where the operator can change attributes of the user, and it calls an edit method in your controller (not index), the patch is what happens when the operator submits the form and that updates the user attributes, calls an update method in your controller which persists the changes to the database... unless there's errors in validation in which case you would re-render the edit view so that the operator can correct the errors.

@SteveTurczyn so what action should I use to display the list of users and enable the update of one value for each of them? Index can list all the users, I can put in the user row a button for patch but the result will be redirection to another url which I would like to avoid.

I would suggest you should start here with some Rails basics like the getting started guide instead of trying to figure everything out as you go along. Both the "error" and your follow up questions are Rails 101 stuff.

@mila002 you shouldn't wish to avoid going to another url.  If you use the same url that endpoint becomes responsible for multiple actions, and it'll quickly become a mess.  You can always have your edit / update methods redirect back to the index view when they've completed.

@SteveTurczyn I did as you wrote. Edit link leads to edit.html.erb and after submitting redirects back to index. Thank for giving me better underdstanding.
